# 2 cpp en Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Buenas, soy nuevo en esto, y tengo una pequeña duda.

La cosa es que tengo una solución que tiene 2 proyectos, uno se llama Servidor y otro Cliente( el codigo de ellos es casi exacto a este https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx ). Compilan sin errores ambos.

El problema es que cuando hacia el <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> del servidor iba bien, se abría la consola y no aparecía nada, pero en principio tenia que ser así. Pero cuando me ponía en el cliente y le daba a run se me abría otra consola(correcto es lo que quiero) pero en la consola salía

> " bind failed with error: 10048"

Como no estaba seguro de cual fallaba si el servidor o el cliente(las 2 consolas eran iguales)puse un `cout` "Servidor"  en el código del servidor y otro "Cliente" en el del cliente.

Bien pues lo que me sale es que al runear el servidor sale la consola con "Servidor" escrito(bien!) y al intentar runear el cliente sale otra consola con "Servidor blind failed..." . Así que me abre 2 veces el cpp del servidor.

Vale la cosa es ¿cómo puedo ejecutar el cliente?, ¿Por qué me ejecuta solo el servidor?

Para que quede claro, mi objetivo es hacer funcionar el ejemplo del link (ahí están el código del servidor y del cliente) con 2 consolas abiertas al mismo tiempo en el mismo ordenador.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sugerencia: reemplaza en el main() de tu cliente por un simple `printf("soy el cliente\n"); exit(0);` para asegurarte de que estás compilando y corriendo el código correcto.

Answer (score 2):

Si realizas boton derecho del mouse sobre el proyecto cliente en el `Solution Explorer` deberias poder ver la opcion que permite cambiar cual es el proyecto que inicia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero hay otras formas, podrias iniciar dos proyectos de forma simultanea, para esto solo tienes que hacer boton derecho del mouse sobre la solucion y del menu seleccionar `Set StartUp Projects` veras un dialogo como el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde podras definir multimples project para que inicien cuando inicies desde el Visual Studio.